# how many space character in field?

Tags: mysql

Excuse me for bad English.  I have a table with a field called Subject . The value of this field is any kind of string. is there a way to find how many space char in per field . for example for "mme mme" is one and for "mme" is zero and for "mme mme mme" is two.

Comment: "have a table " does this means a table in database and if in database please be specific about you IT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it with PHP, you can use substr_count.

```
substr_count(STRING_HERE, " ");
```

[Docs to substr_count(); (PHP.NET)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

It will return the number of spaces as you needed.

Answer (score 1):

From [MySQL List](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/208885):

`select length(Subject) - length(replace(Subject, ' ', ''))`

Or this:

`SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(Subject) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(Subject, ' ', '')) as 
num_spaces FROM my_table;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT length(Subject) - length(replace(Subject, ' ', '')) FROM table;
```